# Is it possible to call an apex method in javascript quote calculator plugin?

Tags: apex, javascript, cpq

Is there a way to invoke apex method in custom script( JavaScript Quote Calculator Plugin)?''I read the documentation but apex seems to only be called in the old calculator rather than the Javascript Quote Calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSQCP runs on Heroku and includes the JSForce library that lets you query objects in your org. You should also be able to make calls to Apex that are exposed as REST endpoints using the [Apex REST features of JSForce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#apex-rest).